# Xamarin.Forms binding does not work with nested custom controls

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, xaml-binding

I'm trying to create a simple (sudoku) grid, which basically consists of 9 custom (grid) controls, where each of them contain 9 other custom (grid) controls. However the binding doesn't seem to be working in the **GridCell** control. The outer **GridBigCell** control seems to be working fine, I can see that it binds to the **OuterCell** property when debugging.

The code is pretty simple and this is probably not even a good way for creating such a grid, but at this point I'm just curious what's the issue here :)

MainPage.xaml:

```c#
    <Grid>
        <controls:GridBigCell Grid.Row="0"
                              Grid.Column="0"
                              OuterCell="{Binding Grid[0]}" />
        <controls:GridBigCell Grid.Row="0"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              OuterCell="{Binding Grid[1]}" />
        <controls:GridBigCell Grid.Row="0"
                              Grid.Column="2"
                              OuterCell="{Binding Grid[2]}" />
        <controls:GridBigCell Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.Column="0"
                              OuterCell="{Binding Grid[3]}" />
        <controls:GridBigCell Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              OuterCell="{Binding Grid[4]}" />
        <controls:GridBigCell Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.Column="2"
                              OuterCell="{Binding Grid[5]}" />
        <controls:GridBigCell Grid.Row="2"
                              Grid.Column="0"
                              OuterCell="{Binding Grid[6]}" />
        <controls:GridBigCell Grid.Row="2"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              OuterCell="{Binding Grid[7]}" />
        <controls:GridBigCell Grid.Row="2"
                              Grid.Column="2"
                              OuterCell="{Binding Grid[8]}" />
    </Grid>
```

GridBigCell control:

```c#
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      x:Class="Sudoku.Controls.GridCell"
      x:Name="this">
    ...
//grid definitions
    ...
    <controls:GridCell Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Cell="{Binding OuterCell[0], Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    <controls:GridCell Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Cell="{Binding OuterCell[1], Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    <controls:GridCell Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Cell="{Binding OuterCell[2], Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    <controls:GridCell Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Cell="{Binding OuterCell[3], Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    <controls:GridCell Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Cell="{Binding OuterCell[4], Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    <controls:GridCell Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Cell="{Binding OuterCell[5], Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    <controls:GridCell Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Cell="{Binding OuterCell[6], Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    <controls:GridCell Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Cell="{Binding OuterCell[7], Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    <controls:GridCell Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Cell="{Binding OuterCell[8], Source={x:Reference this}}" />
</Grid>
```

```c#
public partial class GridBigCell : Grid
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty OuterCellProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(OuterCell),
            typeof(OuterCell),
            typeof(GridBigCell));

        public OuterCell OuterCell
        {
            get => (OuterCell)GetValue(OuterCellProperty);
            set => SetValue(OuterCellProperty, value);
        }

        public GridBigCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

GridCell:

```c#
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      x:Class="Sudoku.Controls.GridCell"
      x:Name="this">
    ...
    <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
           Grid.RowSpan="3"
           Text="{Binding Cell.Number, Source={x:Reference this}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

```c#
public partial class GridCell : Grid
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CellProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Cell),
            typeof(Cell),
            typeof(GridCell));

        public Cell Cell
        {
            get => (Cell)GetValue(CellProperty);
            set => SetValue(CellProperty, value);
        }

        public GridCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Models:

```c#
public class GameGrid : BindableBase
    {
        public OuterCell this[int i]
        {
            get => OuterCells[i];
            set => OuterCells[i] = value;
        }

        public OuterCell[] OuterCells { get; set; }

        public GameGrid()
        {
            OuterCells = new OuterCell[9];
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                OuterCells[i] = new OuterCell();
            }
        }
    }

public class Cell : BindableBase
    {
        public int Number { get; set; } = 1;

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        public bool IsInvalid { get; set; }

        public Note[] Notes { get; set; }

        public Cell()
        {
            Notes = new Note[9];
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                Notes[i] = new Note(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }

public class OuterCell : BindableBase
    {
        public Cell this[int i]
        {
            get => Cells[i];
            set => Cells[i] = value;
        }

        public Cell[] Cells { get; set; } = new Cell[9];

        public OuterCell()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                Cells[i] = new Cell();
            }
        }
    }
```

PropertyChanged is handled by Fody.PropertyChanged library.

Comment: What is the phenomenon when not working.

Comment: It seems that the Cell value is not being set in the GridCell control - it’s always null, so Cell.Number displays nothing.

Comment: Got it , I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, managed to fix it by REMOVING the GridBigCell.xaml & cs and creating it again. Why has this worked? No idea.

Comment: Do you by any chance have more information on this? I'm in the same boat and have tried deleting and recreating...